# How to get notified when to turn using Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

In my mobile app on android, user points a place where he wants to go and the path is then generated by google maps. I need to be told by Google Maps that, for example, right now that guy 'Dave' will have to turn. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should be aware that Google Maps Platform Terms of Service have certain restrictions regarding creation of real-time or turn-by-turn navigation. Basically, you are not allowed to create such functionality in you app.

Have a look at section 3.2.4 'Restrictions Against Misusing the Services' of ToS. In paragraph (c) you will find the following

> **No Re-Creating Google Products or Features.** Customer will not use the Services to create a product or service with features that are substantially similar to or that re-create the features of another Google product or service...
>
> For example, Customer will not: ...
>
> (iv) combine data from the Directions API, Geolocation API, and Maps SDK for Android to create real-time navigation functionality substantially similar to the functionality provided by the Google Maps for Android mobile app.

source: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license

That means that the only allowed option according to the ToS is redirect your users to Google Maps app where they can use navigation mode.

You should create an intent that opens the Google Maps native app in navigation mode. There is a Google Maps URLs that allows to construct a universal, cross-platform URL to launch Google Maps intents from your application. You can open navigation mode of native app following this documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action

Code snapshot might be

```
String url = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=Madrid,Spain&origin=Barcelona,Spain&waypoints=Zaragoza|Huesca&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate";           
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple.

When you select the destination and the path is generated, there are 3 basic icons that appears on the right hand side: The Compass, The Search and The Speaker icon.

You have to make sure you set the speakers to Unmuted once you do that you will get the all notification about the journey, Like which route to stay on, left/Right Directions and the distance for the next action.

[image: image 1]

If you keep it mute you will not receive any audio notification

[image: image 2]

and if you select alert only then it will only alert you about important notifications, Like Left, right , U-Turn , Taking Service Roads Etc.

[image: image 3]

And Above all this you have to make sure your is active for Notification under sound settings. (differs from device to device)

Hope this details help you.

Comment: I'll clarify a bit my question. I need to get told by Google Maps that, for example, right now that guy Dave will have to turn.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the turn by turn directions from Google, however, the easiest way is to just send the start and end location to google maps and take the user out of your app, into google maps and let that give the turn by turn direction with voice:

```
public void GoSend(View button) {
    String start = "";
    String dest = "";

    try {
        start = URLEncoder.encode(startAddress, "utf-8");
        dest = URLEncoder.encode(destAddress, "utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + start + "&daddr=" + dest));
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
    startActivity(intent);
  }
```

Comment: I need to get it not just by voice but by some sort of callback function(if that's what it's called), so that I can send a signal to another device. Do you maybe know how to do it?

Comment: No, I don't.  I know how to get the list of directions, broken into individual 'paths' which correspond to each instruction (turn right, turn left, stay left) but you would need to track the users current location and see when he is near the start point of any of those paths.  It wouldn't be easy...

Comment: That would be helpful. Could you send me a link on how to do it?

Comment: Can't remember the link, but I'll post the classes I use, don't know how much it will help!

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity

```
public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
public final static String MODE_TRANSIT = "transit";
public final static String MODE_CYCLING = "cycling";
public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

private ArrayList<SearchItem> directionSteps;
private ArrayList <LatLng> directionPoints;

...
            switch(checkedId) {
            case R.id.btnDriving:
                sMode = GMapV3Direction.MODE_DRIVING;
                 break;
            case R.id.btnTransit:
                sMode = GMapV3Direction.MODE_TRANSIT;
                break;
            case R.id.btnCycling:
                sMode = GMapV3Direction.MODE_CYCLING;
                 break;
            case R.id.btnWalking:
                sMode = GMapV3Direction.MODE_WALKING;
                break;
            }

            findDirectionsAddress(startAddress, destAddress, sMode );
...

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void findDirectionsAddress(String fromPosition, String toPosition, String mode)
{
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask3.USER_CURRENT_ADDRESS, String.valueOf(fromPosition));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask3.DESTINATION_ADDRESS, String.valueOf(toPosition));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DIRECTIONS_MODE, mode);
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DIRECTIONS_LANGUAGE, (String) getResources().getText(R.string.language));

    GetDirectionsAsyncTask3 asyncTask = new GetDirectionsAsyncTask3(this);
    asyncTask.execute(map);

    GetDirectionsAsyncTask4 asyncTask2 = new GetDirectionsAsyncTask4(this);
    asyncTask2.execute(map);

}

// Handle the turn by turn text directions
public void handleTurnByTurnResult(ArrayList<SearchItem> directionSteps)
{

    this.directionSteps = directionSteps;


    Log.d("Test", "Steps:" + directionSteps.size());
    adapter = new PickListAdapter(this, this.directionSteps);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

// Handle the lat/lons of each step
public void handleGetDirectionsResult(ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints)
{
    this.directionPoints = directionPoints;

   Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

    int width = config.screenWidthDp;
    int height = config.screenHeightDp;

    if (calcPolyline != null) {
        calcPolyline.remove();
    }

    LatLngBounds.Builder bounds = null;
    bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder(); 
    boolean foundOne = false;

    bounds.include(currentLatLng);

    if ((theTrip.getStartAddress().getLatitude() != 0.0) && (theTrip.getStartAddress().getLongitude() !=0.0)) {

        bounds.include(new LatLng(theTrip.getStartAddress().getLatitude(), theTrip.getStartAddress().getLongitude()));

    }

    if ((theTrip.getDestinationAddress().getLatitude() != 0.0) && (theTrip.getDestinationAddress().getLongitude() !=0.0)) {

        bounds.include(new LatLng(theTrip.getDestinationAddress().getLatitude(), theTrip.getDestinationAddress().getLongitude()));

    }

    PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(15).color(Color.BLUE);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoints.size() ; i++)
    {
        rectLine.add((LatLng) directionPoints.get(i));
        bounds.include((LatLng) directionPoints.get(i));
        foundOne = true;
    }

    for (SegmentItem item : theTrip.getPathSegments()) {

        pathDynamic = new PolylineOptions().width(20).color(Color.RED);
        pathDynamic.addAll(decode(item.getEncodedPath()));

        for (int i = 0; i < pathDynamic.getPoints().size(); i++) {
            LatLng point = pathDynamic.getPoints().get(i);
            bounds.include(point);
        }

    }

    if (mMap != null) {
        calcPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
        if (foundOne == true) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds.build(), width, height, 40));
        }
    }
}
```

GMapV3Direction.java

```
package org.myapp;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.venturacounty.hsamileage.model.SearchItem;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class GMapV3Direction {
public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
public final static String MODE_TRANSIT = "transit";
public final static String MODE_CYCLING = "cycling";
public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

public GMapV3Direction() { }

public Document getDocument(String start, String dest, String mode, String language) {

    try {
        start = URLEncoder.encode(start, "utf-8");
        dest = URLEncoder.encode(dest, "utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    long milliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long seconds = milliseconds/1000;

    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?departure_time="
            + seconds
            + "&origin=" + start
            + "&destination=" + dest
            + "&language=" + language
            + "&sensor=false&mode=" + mode;

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public String getDurationText (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
    Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
    return node2.getTextContent();
}

public int getDurationValue (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}

public String getDistanceText (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
    Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
    return node2.getTextContent();
}

public int getDistanceValue (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}

public String getStartAddress (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String getEndAddress (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String getCopyRights (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public ArrayList<SearchItem> getTurnByTurn (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
    ArrayList<SearchItem> listDirections = new ArrayList<SearchItem>();
    nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
    if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

            Node distanceNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "distance"));
            nl3 = distanceNode.getChildNodes();
            Node textNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "text"));
            String distance = textNode.getTextContent();

            Node durationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "duration"));
            nl3 = durationNode.getChildNodes();
            textNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "text"));
            String duration = textNode.getTextContent();

            Node instructionsNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "html_instructions"));
            String instructions = instructionsNode.getTextContent();
            String details = distance + " -- " + duration;


            listDirections.add(new SearchItem(instructions, details, "", false));
        }
    }

    return listDirections;
}


public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
    ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
    if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

            Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
            ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
            for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                LatLng item = (LatLng) arr.get(j);
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude));
            }

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        }
    }

    return listGeopoints;
}

private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
        if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;
    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;                 shift += 5;             } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;                 shift += 5;             } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
        poly.add(position);
    }
    return poly;
}
}
```

GetDirectionAsyncTask.java

```
package org.myapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

import org.myapp.model.SearchItem;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GetDirectionsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Map<String, String>, Object, ArrayList<SearchItem>>
{
public static final String USER_CURRENT_LAT = "user_current_lat";
public static final String USER_CURRENT_LONG = "user_current_long";
public static final String DESTINATION_LAT = "destination_lat";
public static final String DESTINATION_LONG = "destination_long";
public static final String DIRECTIONS_MODE = "directions_mode";
public static final String DIRECTIONS_LANGUAGE = "directions_language";
private PickerActivity activity;
private Exception exception;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public GetDirectionsAsyncTask(PickerActivity pickerActivity)
{
    super();
    this.activity = pickerActivity;
}

public void onPreExecute()
{
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    progressDialog.setTitle((String) this.activity.getResources().getText(R.string.directions));
    progressDialog.setMessage((String) this.activity.getResources().getText(R.string.calculating_directions));
    progressDialog.show();
}

public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<SearchItem> result)
{
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    if (exception == null)
    {
     // activity.handleGetDirectionsResult(result);
        activity.handleTurnByTurnResult(result);
    }
    else
    {
        processException();
    }
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<SearchItem> doInBackground(Map<String, String>... params)
{
    Map<String, String> paramMap = params[0];
    try
    {
        LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(USER_CURRENT_LAT)) , Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(USER_CURRENT_LONG)));
        LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(DESTINATION_LAT)) , Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(DESTINATION_LONG)));
        String sMode = paramMap.get(DIRECTIONS_MODE);
        String sLanguage = paramMap.get(DIRECTIONS_LANGUAGE);
        GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();
        Document doc = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition, sMode, sLanguage);
        // ArrayList directionPoints = md.getDirection(doc);
        ArrayList<SearchItem> directionSteps = md.getTurnByTurn(doc);
        return directionSteps;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        exception = e;
        return null;
    }
}

private void processException()
{
    Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.string.error_when_retrieving_data), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

GetDirectionsAsyncTask3.java

```
package org.myapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

import org.myapp.model.SearchItem;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GetDirectionsAsyncTask3 extends AsyncTask<Map<String, String>, Object, ArrayList<SearchItem>>
{
public static final String USER_CURRENT_ADDRESS = "user_current_address";
public static final String DESTINATION_ADDRESS = "destination_address";
public static final String DIRECTIONS_MODE = "directions_mode";
public static final String DIRECTIONS_LANGUAGE = "directions_language";
private PickerActivity activity;
private Exception exception;

public GetDirectionsAsyncTask3(PickerActivity pickerActivity)
{
    super();
    this.activity = pickerActivity;
}

public void onPreExecute()
{
 }

public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<SearchItem> result)
{
    if (exception == null)
    {
        // Task4 handles direction points
        // activity.handleGetDirectionsResult(result);
        // Task3 handles direction text steps
        activity.handleTurnByTurnResult(result);
    }
    else
    {
        processException();
    }
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<SearchItem> doInBackground(Map<String, String>... params)
{
    Map<String, String> paramMap = params[0];
    try
    {
        String fromPosition = paramMap.get(USER_CURRENT_ADDRESS);
        String toPosition = paramMap.get(DESTINATION_ADDRESS);
        String mode = paramMap.get(DIRECTIONS_MODE);
        String sLanguage = paramMap.get(DIRECTIONS_LANGUAGE);
        GMapV3Direction md = new GMapV3Direction();

        Document doc = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition, mode, sLanguage);
        // Task4 handles direction points
        // ArrayList directionPoints = md.getDirection(doc);
        // Task3 handles direction steps
        ArrayList<SearchItem> directionSteps = md.getTurnByTurn(doc);
        return directionSteps;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        exception = e;
        return null;
    }
}

private void processException()
{
    Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.string.error_when_retrieving_data), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

GetDirectionsAsyncTask4.java

```
package org.myapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GetDirectionsAsyncTask4 extends AsyncTask<Map<String, String>, Object, ArrayList<LatLng>>
{
public static final String USER_CURRENT_ADDRESS = "user_current_address";
public static final String DESTINATION_ADDRESS = "destination_address";
public static final String DIRECTIONS_MODE = "directions_mode";
public static final String DIRECTIONS_LANGUAGE = "directions_language";
private PickerActivity activity;
private Exception exception;

public GetDirectionsAsyncTask4(PickerActivity pickerActivity)
{
    super();
    this.activity = pickerActivity;
}

public void onPreExecute()
{
}

public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<LatLng> result)
{
    if (exception == null)
    {
    // Task4 handles the directions points
        activity.handleGetDirectionsResult(result);

    // Task3 handles the directions text results
    // activity.handleTurnByTurnResult(result);
    }
    else
    {
        processException();
    }
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<LatLng> doInBackground(Map<String, String>... params)
{
    Map<String, String> paramMap = params[0];
    try
    {
        String fromPosition = paramMap.get(USER_CURRENT_ADDRESS);
        String toPosition = paramMap.get(DESTINATION_ADDRESS);
        String mode = paramMap.get(DIRECTIONS_MODE);
        String sLanguage = paramMap.get(DIRECTIONS_LANGUAGE);
        GMapV3Direction md = new GMapV3Direction();
        Document doc = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition, mode, sLanguage);

        // Task4 handles the directions points
        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints = md.getDirection(doc);

        // Task3 handles the directions text results
        // ArrayList directionSteps = md.getTurnByTurn(doc);
        return directionPoints;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        exception = e;
        return null;
    }
}

private void processException()
{
    Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.string.error_when_retrieving_data), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```