# Draw a route b/n two point on Android Fragment Activity

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to the android app development and any help would be much appreciated. I am currently working on an android app, and want to draw a route between two points and also find the distance between them.

I entered the Server-Key and also tried it with API key from Google.

I have tried to draw the route based on what i have read on other sites but, the route isn't drawn, but the distance is calculated. But i want to draw the route and find the distance between them.

I have the following code in my GlobalVariables.java

```
     StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
     urlString.append("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
     urlString.append("?origin=");// from
     urlString.append(Double.toString(pickupLatitude));
     urlString.append(",");
     urlString
             .append(Double.toString( pickupLongitude));
     urlString.append("&destination=");// to
     urlString
             .append(Double.toString( dropoffLatitude));
     urlString.append(",");
     urlString.append(Double.toString(dropoffLongitude));
     urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=w&alternatives=true");
     urlString.append("&key=my api key");
     return urlString.toString();
 }
```

The following is written in the MapsFragment

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        mapView =  view.findViewById(R.id.pickupmap);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.onResume();
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mMap = googleMap;
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                //currentLocation = new LatLng(GlobalVariables.passengerCurrentLatitude, GlobalVariables.passengerCurrentLongitude);
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(currentLocation).zoom(20).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                        mMap.clear();
                        getDirection();
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Pickup Location").snippet("Pick me up here")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pickup)));
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Dropoff Location").snippet("Drop me off here").draggable(true).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_dropoff)));
                        mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);


                        GlobalVariables.passengerDropoffLatitude = latLng.latitude;
                        GlobalVariables.passengerDropoffLongitude = latLng.longitude;
                        GlobalVariables.distance = GlobalVariables.CalculateDistance(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude,
                                latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);

                        //Getting the URL
                        url = GlobalVariables.makeURL(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude,
                                latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);

                        Log.d("Pickup Location: ", "Latittude: " + GlobalVariables.passengerCurrentLatitude + " \nLongitude: " + GlobalVariables.passengerCurrentLongitude);
                        Log.d("Drop off Location: ", "" + "Latitude: "  + latLng.latitude + " \nLongitude: " +  latLng.longitude);
                        Log.d("Distance: ", "" + GlobalVariables.distance);

                    }
                });


            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private void getDirection(){
        //Showing a dialog till we get the route
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Getting Route", "Please wait...", false, false);

        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        //Calling the method drawPath to draw the path
                        drawPath(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        //Adding the request to request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public void drawPath(String  result) {
        //Getting both the coordinates
        LatLng from = new LatLng(GlobalVariables.passengerCurrentLatitude,GlobalVariables.passengerCurrentLongitude);
        LatLng to = new LatLng(GlobalVariables.passengerDropoffLatitude,GlobalVariables.passengerDropoffLongitude);

        //Calculating the distance in meters
        Double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(from, to);

        //Displaying the distance
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + distance + " Meters",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        try {
            //Parsing json
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
            JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
            List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);
            Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .addAll(list)
                    .width(20)
                    .color(Color.RED)
                    .geodesic(true)
            );


        }
        catch (JSONException e) {

        }
    }

    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng( (((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5) ));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
```

Comment: As Michael mentioned above, you are iterating through routes, it can also be achieved. Can you debug the app by adding a break point in your MapsFragment, at the line which you call the drawParh mehod and see what is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be iterating through "routes", but in the code I'm using, I'm iterating through 'steps'.  I got my code from here [How to get notified when to turn using Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714597/how-to-get-notified-when-to-turn-using-google-maps/55715050), and you'll see that you collect an array of lat/lons, then you build a polyline based on that array of points, then you add the polyline to the map.